# How to construct a set of vectors orthogonal to other set

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, inner-products

If I have a set of Linear Independent vectors $\{v_i\}^d_{i=1}$ that span a space V, (they are not orthogonal in general). How can one construct a set of vectors $\{w_i\}^d_{i=1}$ that fulfills, $$\langle v_i,w_j\rangle=\delta_{ij}$$
That involves the inner product.

In a book I've seen a formula that involves the determinant. But is not explained how to obtain it, if someone can give me some help with that.

Comment: What does "asegurate" mean? I don't think that is an English word...

Comment: Sorry, I was sure that this word exists, I just changed it. I mean that is a general linar independent set, so the vectors could or couldn't be orthogonal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets denote by $B=\left(b_{ij}\right)$ the matrix with components
$$b_{ij}:=\left\langle v_i,v_j\right\rangle.$$
Also, let's assume such $w_j$ as in your question exist. Let $A=\left(a_{ij}\right)$ be the matrix that satisfies
$$w_j=\sum_k a_{jk}v_k.$$
Such $a_{jk}$'s must exist since the $v_j$ form a basis of $V$.
Now, we want:
$$\delta_{ij}=\langle v_i,w_j\rangle=\sum_k a_{jk}\langle v_i,v_k\rangle=\sum_ka_{jk}b_{ki}.$$
Thus, we find
$$A=B^{-1}$$
from which we get the $w_j$'s easily via the formula provided above.

Comment: Okay, understanded. But when you are considering the step $\sum_k a_{jk}\langle v_i,v_k\rangle=\sum_k a_{jk}b_{ki}$. How is done the assumption  $$\langle v_i,v_k\rangle=b_{ik}=b_{ki}=\langle v_k,v_i\rangle$$ Why B matrix is symmetric?

Comment: @Euler Well, usually (at least for real vector spaces) it is implicitly assumed that the inner product is symmetric, that is, that $\langle v,w\rangle=\langle w,v\rangle$ for all vectors $v,w$. We have to be a bit more careful for complex vector spaces, where we would get the complex conjugate of $B$ instead.